# Adding more rows in other column to mistmatch rows in another column

Tags: tabularray

I've been trying to make this possible with latex for a while now. I am using tabularray for this.

Here is how I have it in Microsoft Word:
[image: IN WORD]

Here is what I have so far in Latex:

[image: IN LATEX]

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\centerline{\textbf{Table 1: Position \& Time Data}}

\centering
\begin{tblr}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
t (s) & x (cm) & $\Delta$x (cm) & V$_{\text{avg}}$ (cm/s) \\ \hline
1-1 & 1-2 & \SetCell[r=2]{c, black!50} & \SetCell[r=2]{c, black!50} \\ \hline
2-1 & 2-2 &  &  \\ \hline
3-1 & 3-2 & 1.5-3 & 1.5-4 \\ \hline
4-1 & 4-2 & 2.5-3 & 2.5-4 \\ \hline
5-1 & 5-2 & \SetCell[r=2]{c, black!50} & \SetCell[r=2]{c, black!50} \\ \hline
6-1 & 6-2 & 6-3 & 6-4 \\ \hline
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after.  I had to add a 5th column in order to align the rows, although that is a problem peculiar to tblr.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\centerline{\textbf{Table 1: Position \& Time Data}}

\centering
\begin{tblr}{|c|c|c|c|l@{}}
\cline{1-4}
t (s) & x (cm) & $\Delta$x (cm) & V$_{\text{avg}}$ (cm/s) & \strut\\ \cline{1-4}
\SetCell[r=2]{c} 1-1 & \SetCell[r=2]{c} 1-2 & \SetCell{black!50} & \SetCell{black!50} & \strut \\ \cline{3-4}
 & & \SetCell[r=2]{c} 1.5-3 & \SetCell[r=2]{c} 1.5-4 & \strut\\ \cline{1-2}
\SetCell[r=2]{c} 2-1 & \SetCell[r=2]{c} 2-2 & & & \strut \\ \cline{3-4}
 & & \SetCell[r=2]{c} 2.5-3 & \SetCell[r=2]{c} 2.5-4 & \strut\\ \cline{1-2}
\SetCell[r=2]{c} 5-1 & \SetCell[r=2]{c} 5-2 & & & \strut\\ \cline{3-4}
& & \SetCell{black!50} & \SetCell{black!50} & \strut \\ \cline{1-4}
\end{tblr}\hspace{-\tabcolsep}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: To save the next person time on how to expand it so that it is longer, all you do is copy-paste the [following lines](https://imgur.com/virBdip) under each other and the "chain" will continue